# How can I change reply-to email adress of contact form when using transactional email template?

Tags: email, email-templates, transactional, contact-us

I am using a custom template for the contact form because I need a unique subject line for incoming contact form. I got that working by using a custom transactional email template. But now I came across a new problem: the reply-to email is set to an email address of our store instead of the person who filled in the form.

How can I use the customer's email address as the reply-to address?

Comment: Which contact form??

Comment: The default contact form of Magento...?

Answer (score 3):

The code which sends the contacts email is:

```
$post = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
// ... more code ...
$mailTemplate->setDesignConfig(array('area' => 'frontend'))
    ->setReplyTo($post['email'])
    ->sendTransactional(
        Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_TEMPLATE),
        Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_SENDER),
        Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_RECIPIENT),
        null,
        array('data' => $postObject)
    );
```

You can see, it uses the value `email` which was posted from the contacts form, which actually is exactly what you want. Some modification you or an extension you installed must have changed the default behavior.

Comment: Hi thanks for your anwser. I am not using an extension or whatsoever. I just used a custom template from the Magento settings for tranactional emails. I was hoping for a non-codeing solution.

Comment: You must have broken the default reply_to functionality with your custom contacts template. The email template has no part in that. Post your custom *contacts/form.phtml* template for further info.